# ActiveMQ JMS message selection

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

In Java is it possible to select a message from a queue with JMS and ActiveMQ, knowing its correlationID?

The idea is to be able to know a message is the response of what message that have been sent before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [complete example](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) how to handle correlationID.

Key methods from JMS spec are [getJMSCorrelationID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSCorrelationID()) and [setJMSCorrelationID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you, 
What I want  to do is to  use a servlet to send an authentication request to a database using a xml with jaxb to a program database which will check and send a response in xml format. So, many users can use the application, how can I link a response from the database program using the correlationID to the correct user?

Comment: Could you show your code? What is not working if you do it like in the example above?